# How to extend authentication lifetime for TFS access?

Tags: authentication, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I use the following code to access TFS:

```
using (var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri))
{
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
    ...
```

If my authentication is still valid it simply goes on. When it is not and my program runs under VS I am asked for login/password and after logging in I can proceed (when running my program from desktop it just throws an exception, another oddity).

The problem is that for some months now the lifetime of authentication shrunk to something like a week, so now I log in, and log in, and log in, and... which is super annoying.

So, is there a way to extend the lifetime of positive authentication?

Comment: Did you check the "Credntials Manager"?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, I did now, what should I do there?

Comment: Try to remove the TFS credentials and add them again.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, it seems I don't have TFS credentials stored at all. I can see others like Skype, OneDrive, but not TFS.